# Exception, need to learn what is wrong?

Tags: java, exception

{

```
private static final int StringIndexOutOfBoundsException = 0;
//values shared within the class
private static int sideA = 0;
private static int sideB = 0;


//main method
public static void main(String [] args)


{

System.out.println("Usage: Supply 2 integer values as triangle sides."); 
System.out.println("    A-integer value");
System.out.println("    B-integer value");
System.out.println("    C-attempt a pythagorean calculation");
System.out.println("    Q-quit the program");


String value = null;
String side;
char c = 0;

int s1 =StringIndexOutOfBoundsException;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean carryOn=true;
while(carryOn)                //loop until user has finished.
{
    side = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A or B?");
try
{
    c =side.charAt(0);
} catch(NullPointerException NP){
    System.out.println("Thanks you are done!");
}


    switch(c)                 //which side is the user trying to set
    {
    case 'Q':
        carryOn= false; //quit the program
        break;

    case 'A':
        try{
        value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter A"); 
        sideA = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch(NumberFormatException NF){
            System.out.println("Thats not a number. Type in an integer.");
            break;
        }
        if (sideA<=0)
        {
        System.out.println("Cannot compute because A is zero. Try another integer");
        break;
        }
        if(sideA>0)
        {
            System.out.println("You've inputed an A value. That value is "+sideA);
            break;
        }

        break;

    case 'B':
            try{
            value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter B"); 
            sideB = Integer.parseInt(value);
            } catch(NumberFormatException NF){
                System.out.println("Thats not a number. Type in an integer.");
                break;
            }
            if (sideB<=0)
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot compute because B is zero. Try another integer");
                break;
                }
            if(sideB>0)
            {
                System.out.println("You've inputed an B value. That value is "+sideB);
                break;
            }


            break;

    case 'C':          //calculate an answer
        double temporary = (sideA * sideA) + (sideB * sideB);
        if(sideA <=0 && sideB <=0){
            System.out.println("You don't have triangle. Try again");
            break;
        }
        double result = java.lang.Math.sqrt(temporary);
        System.out.println("The hypotenuse value is "+result);
        break;
    }



    }
System.out.println("Thank you. Goodbye!");
return;

    }
```

}

and my error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0  at
>   java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)  at
>   lab1.lab01.main(lab01.java:42)

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Have you looked at line 42?

Comment: It's staring you right in the face. Read the exception name. Go to the line indicated. Fix things.

Comment: Could the message be *any* clearer than it already is???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a `String` isn't *exactly* a `char[]` as it is in C, for certain operations, it's better to think of it like one.

When you attempt to index into an array that is empty or uninitialized, you'll get a similar exception - `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  This means that you're attempting to index into something that doesn't exist.

We know that an array of size N can be indexed to location N-1.  For N = 0, we would (by math) be indexing into location -1, [which is not permissible.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

The same thing is happening when you perform `charAt()`.  You're attempting to retrieve a value that doesn't exist.  In other words:  **your String is empty.**

The culprit is this line:

```
c =side.charAt(0);
```

If `side` is empty, you're stuck.

When you go to retrieve a value for `side`, as in this line:

```
side = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A or B?");
```

...add a check to ensure that it isn't empty, and wait until you get a valid length.

```
String side = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A or B?");
while(side.isEmpty()) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Invalid input!");
   side = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "A or B?");
}
```